# Why sometime dropdownlist value can not be retrieved in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a form that use DropDownListFor that are set in mvc model. But strangely enough, the current value of them sometimes can not be retrieved in model (sometimes they can). The code is,

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("EditPageSubmit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Destination, Model.Destinations, Model.Destination)%>
...

model.Destinations= (from r in this._repository.Destinations
                                select new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Text = r.Name,
                                    Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)r.DestinationID),
                                    Selected = false
                                });
Model.Destination = "...";

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult EditPageSubmit(FormCollection collection)
{
    var updatedModel = new SalesViewModel();

    if (TryUpdateModel(updatedModel))
    ...
}
```

Strangely enough, sometimes (often when dropdownlist is not changed and remains with initial value), updatedModel.Destination is null, and sometimes it is the selected value. I have really no idea on this problem and need help on it. Thanks.

Comment: It is possible that Entity framework eager loading feature has not loaded the data yet. Is _repository.Destinations is marked virtual. i.e. Destination collection property marked virtual.

Comment: No, it is not virtual. I found that if changed to Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Destination, Model.Destinations), ie not initialized by Model.Destination, it will not happen. But initial value of dropdownlist is not set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason. The initialization variable can not be the same as model id. In this case, simply change to Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Destination, Model.Destinations, Model.Destination1) will work.

Comment: mmm thats may be on of the reasons is to have separate view model rather than binding directly with data access models. may be? any way thanks.